# I have userid and password in a .txt file. i want to make a script which send mails to multiple users with the credentials in file

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have Userid and password and mail id in a .txt file. i want to make a script which send mails to multiple users with the credentials in file separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

#get the list of email addresses
LIST=`awk -F"," '{print $3}' maillist.txt`

#convert to array
LIST=($LIST);

#loop through each row, extract credentials and send e-mail.
for (( i=0;i<${#LIST[@]}; i++))
do
  UP=`cat maillist.txt|grep ${LIST[$i]}|awk -F"," '{print $1","$2}'`
  `mail.mailutils -s "subject" ${LIST[$i]} <<< $UP`
done
```

I was not able to test this on my side becasue our box is clogged and does not send e-mails right now.

Replace `maillist.txt` with the name of your file. I assume this file is where you execute the bash script from

Comment: I want to sent diff content { content is password}. In content password mentioned will be changing for all users. i don't have any attachment.

Comment: This is not working for me

Comment: any chance I could take a look at the format of the .txt file?

Comment: file is in this format:
userid,password,email.id

userid and password are the things to be shared in mail. 
email.id - to which we need to send the id and password

Comment: got it. I'll get back to you ASAP

Comment: I hope this works. but unfortunately am not able to install mailutils on my server due to some access issue. is there any other way to do this without mailutils.?

Comment: Thanks Alex. I worked with simple mailx command successfully. :)

Comment: glad I could help!